# Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum CGImageAlphaInfo' to different enumeration type 'CGBitmapinfo' (aka) 'enum CGBitmapInfo') ios 7

Tags: ios, enums

Hi in app using route direction in google map for that i need to update the route while updating its showing some warning like.

> Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum CGImageAlphaInfo' to
>   different enumeration type 'CGBitmapinfo' (aka) 'enum CGBitmapInfo')

This is my code.

```
     -(void) updateRouteView {

         CGContextRef context =     CGBitmapContextCreate(nil,
                                              routeView.frame.size.width,
                                              routeView.frame.size.height,
                                              8,
                                              4 * routeView.frame.size.width,
                                              CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                                              kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

       CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, lineColor.CGColor);
       CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
       CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0);
  }
```

In this above its showing warning in the line.

> kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

In above line its showing the warning please tell me how to resolve this one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax for `CGBitmapContextCreate`

```
CGContextRef CGBitmapContextCreate (
   void *data,
   size_t width,
   size_t height,
   size_t bitsPerComponent,
   size_t bytesPerRow,
   CGColorSpaceRef colorspace,
   CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo
);
```

See the last argument which belong to `CGBitmapInfo`. But you're using `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` which belong to `CGImageAlphaInfo`. So just cast type to `CGBitmapInfo`

Comment: please tell me wt im have to change as im new to ios development im not getting wt ur saying

Comment: Just replace `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` by `kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask`. and check this.

Comment: ya i replaced after i replacing that its hiding  the route map please tell how to resolve this

Comment: Just change with all other too. `kCGBitmapFloatComponents`, `kCGBitmapByteOrderMask`..... It should work.

Comment: its not working i have already used that code in other project there its working fine only here its giving problem

Comment: other project setting may differ with this, because if project setting have arch with 64 bit, this problem will rise due to strict with data types. I'm sure above reason is problem here.

Comment: just replace `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` by `kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault`

Comment: have replace this one also its not working still its hides the route direction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55376/discussion-between-user3614966-and-mani).

Comment: final solution. just cast with type `(CGBitmapInfo) kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast `

Answer (score 0):

Update your code

```
CGContextRef context =CGBitmapContextCreate(nil,routeView.frame.size.width, routeView.frame.size.height,8,4 * routeView.frame.size.width, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just added "(CGBitmapInfo)" and it works

```
-(void) updateRouteView {

         CGContextRef context =     CGBitmapContextCreate(nil,
                                              routeView.frame.size.width,
                                              routeView.frame.size.height,
                                              8,
                                              4 * routeView.frame.size.width,
                                              CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                                              (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

       CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, lineColor.CGColor);
       CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
       CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0);
  }
```